# Continuity and differentiability of piecewise functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

> Let $f_1: [0, 2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f_2 : [0, 2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be functions defined by $$f_1(x) = \left\{
> \begin{aligned} 
> 0, \;0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1\\ 
> 3,  \; 1 \leqslant x \leqslant 2  \\ 
> \end{aligned} 
> \space
> \space
> \text{and}
> \space
> \space
> \right.
> f_2(x) = \left\{
> \begin{aligned} 
> 2, \;x \neq 1\\ 
> 1,  \; x=1  \\ 
> \end{aligned} 
> \right.
> $$
>
> also let $F_1(x) = \int_0^x f_1(t)dt$ and $F_2(x) = \int_0^x f_2(t)dt$

- Determine the functions $F_1$, $F_2$ and find out if they're continuous.
- Find out if the $F_1$ and $F_2$ are differentiable on $(0,2)$

I've been stuck with this for a long time now. It was an given to us as an assigment and couldn't find the answers to it. Would be appreciated if anyone could elaborate on this.

Comment: A graph of the functions and the interpretation of the integral as area under the graph can help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this using first principles.

When $x< 1$, $F_1(x)=\int_0^x0\,\mathrm{d}t=0$.

When $x\geq1$, $F_1(x)=\int_0^x f_1(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^10\,\mathrm{d}t+\int_1^x3\,\mathrm{d}t=3(x-1)$. Notice that $F_1(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$ since $\lim_{x\to 1^-}F_1(x)=\lim_{x\to 1^+}F_1(x)=F_1(1)=0.$ Hence, $F_1$ is continuous.

For differentiable, the only weird situation is at $x=1$ since both $F_1(x)=0$ and $F_1(x)=3(x-1)$ are differentiable separately. Let's show that it is not differentiable using the definition of derivative.

If $F_1'(1)$ exists, then $F_1'(1)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F_1(1+h)-F_1(1)}{h}$. Obviously, the limit has to exist. Start with the leftward limit, which occurs when $h<0$. Then since $1+h<1$, difference quotient satisfies
$$
\frac{F_1(1+h)-F_1(1)}{h}=\frac{0-0}{h}=0.
$$
Since this holds for all $h<0$, in the limit as $h\to 0^-$, the leftward derivative limit is $0$. I.e. $DF_1^-(1)=0$. Now let $h>0$. Then
$$
\frac{F_1(1+h)-F_1(1)}{h}=\frac{3(1+h-1)-0}{h}=3.
$$
Hence, by similar reasoning as the left derivative, it follows that $DF_1^+(1)=3$. As we can see, $F_1'(1)$ cannot exist since the leftward and rightward limits in the difference quotient don't match.

See if you can figure it out for $F_2$. In principle, it's similar, with the main observation that the integral over single points is zero.

**Remark:** You can also see why $F_1$ is not differentiable at $x=1$ by looking at a graph and seeing a sharp corner arise.